# App crashes without throwing any exception in windows phone 8.1 xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am creating a Windows phone 8.1 xaml application. And I used [SlideView : a Facebook-like panel for Windows Phone](https://drive.google.com/a/mobme.in/file/d/0B1XMRqRHI1TXSjFyR0g0eDVyR1E/view). But app crashes each time while i navigating to a new page by a button click which is placed inside slide view. Navigation is successful from the button outside view.

The bad thing is like that it is not throwing any type of exceptions or details. Even it is not not hitting in the App `UnhandledException` event.

```
    public App()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();          
        this.UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
    }

    void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
       //not throwing exception here
    }
```

I want to know, when will happen this condition ? How to get the exception details of which results app crash ? I can fix the problem if I am able to get the exact issue.

Please provide me the solution. My sample is [here](https://drive.google.com/a/mobme.in/file/d/0B1XMRqRHI1TXSjFyR0g0eDVyR1E/view)

Comment: If memory serves: you should be looking for exceptions on OnNavigatedTo or similar. Have you looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigationfailed(v=vs.110).aspx perhaps?

Comment: When it navigated, the entire code in the OnNavigated to method of the page is working and then app crashes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I don't know why but... If you simply add something to the `secnod` page and the problem goes away.</s>

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="second" />
</Grid>
```

I too cannot capture the exception anywhere. I had similar issues before and what I had to was removing code piece by piece to make the exception go away... Clearly something is not right in the WinRT framework.

**Update**

No, the above answer still doesn't fix it. After some further investigation, I've found the right way to get rid of the crash is to call the `Dispatcher`. I believe this is a bug introduced in update 1. Please see this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/azure/en-US/6d1a6be3-096e-4090-a4bd-30d1293697b3/windows-phone-81-update-1-access-violation-when-navigating-using-tapped-event?forum=WindowsPhonePreviewSDK) for reference.

```
private async void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Frame.Navigate(typeof(second)));
}
```

Comment: have you checked my sample?